# On the sum of prime powers

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, zeta-functions

Has anybody investigated the asymptotic growth rate of functions in the form of
$$f(z,n)=\sum\limits_{p\le n}p^z$$
For $Re(z)\ge -1$.
Of course $f(0,n)=\pi (n)$ has an ocean of research surrounding it, but does the function above seem to ring any bells. Any information would be helpful.

I conjecture that for all complex $z$ with $Re(z)\ge-1$, 
$$\sum\limits_{p\le n}p^z\approx\int\limits_{2}^{n}\frac{x^z}{\ln(x)}dx$$
Perhaps this makes things more interesting.

Comment: Why are you interested? Are you looking for something special?

Comment: I was investigating the prime zeta function and ended up making the above conjecture which fitted very well with computation. So I just wanted to know who else had been researching these sums and well, no sea of research have I met, but a veritable jungle indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I called it the truncated Prime zeta function. In a general way you can write any function that sums over primes like this
$$
\sum_{p\le x}f(p)=\int_2^x f(t) d(\pi(t))  =f(t)\pi(t)\biggr|_{2}^{x}+\int_{2}^{x}f'(t)\pi(t)dt.
$$
see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115230/19341). Put in your favorite approximation for $\pi(n)$, like $\frac n{\log n}$, and $f(t)=t^z$ you get:
$$
\sum_{p\le x} p^z \approx \frac {t^{z+1}}{\log t}\Biggr|^x_2 +\int_2^x z\frac {t^{z}}{\log t} dt
$$
close to what you conjecture...

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/237537/19341), [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97891/19341), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/161346/19341), [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/95058/19341) and references therein...Welcome to the jungle!

Comment: Not sure why Antonio removed his comment, but [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49383/19341) needs to show up in the linked section...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it was already in your list :)

Comment: Can you explain the notation d(pi(t)). I understand that the function 'jumps' at primes, but surely at these points, its derivative is +infinity, not 1.

Comment: @ElieBergman I can try: $d\pi(t)$ is a measure. Let me cite Ilya's comment ["the integral is well-defined in the Lebesgue-Stieltjes sense."](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115230/summing-over-general-functions-of-primes-and-an-application-to-prime-zeta-fun#comment267980_115230)